# http call inside ngFor best practice

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, httpclient, angular-promise

I have two models;

```
export interface Student {
    id: string,
    name: string
}

export interface StudentGoal{
    id: string,
    studentId: string,
    goal: string
}
```

I get the students in my StudentService like this:

```
getStudents(): Observable<Student[]> {
    return this.http.get<Student[]>("URL_1");
}
```

I get a student goal like this:

```
getStudentGoal(studendId: string): Observable<StudentGoal> {
    return this.http.get<StudenGoal>("URL_2" + studentId);
}
```

**QUESTION**

What is the **best practice** to get student goal inside *ngFor in my student.goal.component

> .ts

```
private subs = new SubSink()
public students: Student[] = [];
constructor(
    private studentService: StudentService
)

ngOnInit() {
    this.getStudents();
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subs.unsubscribe()
}

getStudents(){
    this.subs.sink = this.studentService.getStudents().subscribe((res: Student[]) => {
         this.students = res
    })
}

getStudentGoal(studentId: number){
    BEST PRACTICE ?
}
```

> .html

```
<div *ngFor="let student of students">
    {{getStudentGoal(student.id).goal}}
</div>
```

Comment: Have you considered to include the goal along with the student objects in the call to `getStudents`? You seem to need it to render the student list itself.

Comment: What you are saying is that I should construct inside the Student model a field "goal": StudentGoal?

Comment: Yes, but populate that from the backend if possible. If you don't have control over the backend, there still are things that you can do to make it work properly.

Comment: That could be a nice and elegant solution, I did think of it for a second. I would like to hear some more opinions though :), and lets assume i do not have control of the backend

Comment: It makes sense to me because you need the goal to render the list. Why not get everything that you need in one go? You can indeed fire a number of requests equal to `students.length` to fetch the extra data that you need, but is it worth it?

Comment: It does makes sence and I agree, but I am no expert on backend dev, and also, there is the discussion that if the backend returns to me a big object with many populated fields, and I rely on that, how scalable and maintainable is this? Isn't it better for the back end to have clear API calls and whatever frontend developer (framework) comes next will handle it as she wishes? Or is it better to have an architecture like this in the backend and everybody follow this one? Big issue I guess? Or maybe not

Answer (score 0):

1.- When we mannage Observables we have two **differents** things: the "response" and the "subscription"

```
this.subscription=myObservable(res=>{
     this.response=res;
})
```

this.subscription is a subscription and only is util when we want unsubscribe. it's NOT the response

2.-When we use in .html observables we can

1. show a variable that we are using inside subscribe function
2. use async pipe

   ```
   {{response|json}}
   //or
   {{myObservable|async}}
   ```

but **not** {{subscription}}

3.-When we mannage a ngFor subscription sometimes is util read all we need. For this we use switchmap and forkJoin

```
allData=this.studentService.getStudents().pipe(
   switchMap(students:any[]=>{
        return forkJoin(students.map(student=>
              this.studentService.getStudentGoal(student.id).pipe(
                   //return all the properties of student
                   //and all the properties of getStudentGoal
                   //in an unique object
                   map(x=>({...student,...x})
              )
        )
   })
)
```

So we can use

```
<div *ngFor="let studentData of allData |async">
{{studentData.id}} {{studetData.goal}}
</div>
```

Comment: Hello Eliseo. I do like your approach, I was thinking about this solution too. Thank you very much! Will consider it more now